# Generating binary numbers recursively?

Tags: binary, recursive-algorithms, number-systems

I want to generate $n$-bit binary numbers $x_i$ , but i do not want to do the loop of decisions by 2 for each $x_i$. I think there is should be a recursive way of generating the binary representation vector for $x_i$ based on previous indices of $i$.

Or if there is another way to directly calculate $x_{i,d}$ as the $d$-th digit of $x_i$ ?

Comment: Maybe a carry look ahead adder, adding 1, would be helpful?: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Comb/lookahead.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is one way to recursively phrase it:
$$
x_{i,d}= 
\begin{cases}
    \neg{x_{{i-1},d}}   & \text{if  } (x_{{i-1},{d-1}}=1 \wedge x_{{i},{d-1}}=0) \vee (d=1) \\
    x_{{i-1},{d}}              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Assuming $d=1$ is the smallest digit and $x_1$ is a $n$-bit binary vector of zeros.